# How do i fix ubuntu if it crashes at start up?can i download version 12 anywhere?

Tags: system-installation

Sometimes i can go as far as see icons, most time it will freeze and just a blank screen.
I replaced win7. Acer aspire ati 3650. 4gb.

It wont let me do anything, reinstalled three times, both with 32 and 64 version. Does ubuntu only work on certain specs?

New to ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can download Ubuntu 12.04.4 here:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

It could be hardware related, I would try Alt + Ctrl + F2, login and type:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

Because, you might just need the ATI wrapper for Ubuntu, however it could be a lot of things, I don't know how you could have peacefully when through the installation without it though.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` might help too.

or maybe bad dvds. I have had bad installs everytime I used the default cd burner in 12.04, I always had to use K3b.